# Modal not working in Ember.js app

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, modal-dialog

I'm developing my portfolio website and I'm having problems getting a modal to work. I'm first keeping it simple and just coding this feature as if this was plain html5.

This is the code:

```
<div class="main-information">
    <div class="main">
        <img src="images/profile.JPG"/>
        <div class="info">
          <h2 class="text-primary">FRANCISCO GOITIA</h2>
          <h3 class="text-primary">SOFTWARE DEVELOPER</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>
                <a class="btn" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#heroku">Heroku</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn" href="https://github.com/frangoitia" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn">Curriculum Vitae</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="heroku" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id=""></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
          The following are some applications I have built and deployed to Heroku. The code for this projects, as well as the code for many more projects and massive open online courses I've taken, can be access in my Github repo:
        </p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          {{#each model as |application|}}
            {{heroku-app application=application}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap is working successfully otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm you have the JS loaded for Bootstrap? You could try finding an object in the inspector console, and then seeing if will auto-complete any BS JS methods. e.g., `window.$modal = $('.modal')`, then `$modal.modal('show')`. If it _is_ loaded, typing `$modal.mo` should show `modal` in the auto-complete. Also, the above code will programatically open your modal if the JS is there.

Comment: That could be _exactly_ what you're saying in that Bootstrap is working successfully, but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: If the modal opens, but there is no content in the `each` area, then there is something weird happening in Ember.

Answer (score 4):

Edit:

I totally misread what you were doing. Your code is correct, but it is likely that you don't have the javascript files for Bootstrap included (or jQuery)

---

So all you are missing is a button that will toggle the modal like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#heroku">
  Toggle Modal
</button>
```

It is the second example in the docs found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Additionally, here is a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ruzakepiqo/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the html you posted is correct, and opens a modal:

http://jsfiddle.net/0s397z3p/

So i suppose that the problem is actually in the wrong use of handlebars `#each` helper:

```
{{#each application in model}}
  {{heroku-app application=application}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The syntax for the each loop has changed recently, the asker is using the correct new one.